# Do we have console for codeigniter

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, django, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have been working on codeigniter recently and I am surprised that I **didn't find** anything **relevant regarding codeigniter console**. So basically I will like to know whether we have console in codeigniter just like we have in rails and django?

Comment: It would if you wrote the scripts to provide the functionality, otherwise no.

Comment: @gwillie Didn't get you, What kind of scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no console.

The closest thing to a console that comes with CI is the [profiler](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html). It offers:

```
benchmarks          Elapsed time of Benchmark points and total execution time
config              CodeIgniter Config variables
controller_info     The Controller class and method requested
get                 Any GET data passed in the request
http_headers        The HTTP headers for the current request
memory_usage        Amount of memory consumed by the current request, in bytes
post                Any POST data passed in the request
queries             Listing of all database queries executed, including execution time
uri_string          The URI of the current request
query_toggle_count  The number of queries after which the query block will default to hidden.
```

Comment: To activate the profiler add '$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);' in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Other than profiler, You can write logs by using log_message('level', 'message') function. Visit http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html for details.

If you are using Firebug in FireFox or Chrome Developer Tools then you can use FirePHP to write logs in the browser console. Install FirePHP in your browser, download FirePHP library and after integrating the library with CodeIgniter you can write logs to your browser console by using the following code.

```
$this->load->library("firephp");
$this->firephp->log("Hello World");
```